# Floating two divs to right next to each other

Tags: html, css

I want to float two divs next to each other on right. The rightmost div has variable text so I want the left div to keep moving left but stick to the right div with variable data.
When ever I do float:right to both the left div replaces the right div.

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class ="left">static data<div>
<div class ="right">variable data<div>
<div class="wrap">

css 
 .left{
   float:right;
   width:69%;
   display:block;
  }
 .right{
  float:right;
  width:28%;
  display:block;
 }
 .wrap{
 width:100%;
 }
```

the right and left divs further have some divs in them but without any classes. How can I handle this issue . The left div takes over the right div when dispalying.

Thanks,

Comment: You might want to use closing tags.

Comment: If you float two elements to one side, the one listed in the source first will be the one furthest on that side... So that means your `left` div will be on the right side of your `right` div.

Answer (score 6):

I think you just want to swap the divs.

The first child div is floated all the way to the rhs

The second right-floated div is displayed to the left of the first one

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cWY2x/)**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class ="right">variable data</div>
    <div class ="left">static data</div>
</div>
```

css

```
 .left, .right{
    float:right;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to trigger something called a block formatting context. Just set the partner's `overflow` property to a value different than the default. If you need backwards support (ie family), play with `zoom: 1;` Also, put the floating divs first.

```
.right {
    width: 28%;
    float: right;
}
.left {
    overflow: auto;
}
.wrap{
    width:100%;
}

<div class="wrap">
    <div class ="right">variable data</div>
    <div class ="left">static data</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GMwjQ/

There already exists a thread that posted this answer somewhere in SO. Can't find it.

Comment: I can't see that `overflow:auto` does anything in this example? As regards floats are concerned, `overflow:auto` (or `hidden`) would normally be applied to a parent element (ie. `.wrap` in this instance) in order to clear floated child elements.

Answer (score 0):

Without swapping the divs in the HTML, float the wrapper div to the right and make the child divs inline-block.

```
css 
 .wrap{
   float: right;
 }
 .left{
   width: 69%;
   display: inline-block;
  }
 .right{
  width: 28%;
  display: inline-block;
 }
```